# Find and replace with sed command for Tcl command args symbol

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I am trying to replace a string in a file which has `tcl` command delimiters '[]' using `sed`

Example:

`string [$HelloWorld]` has to be replace by `$HelloWord`. Please note that it doesn't have brackets and to be modified file is TCL file. How would I do that using `sed` command?

I tried this:

```
sed -i 's@[$HelloWorld]@$HelloWorld@g' <file_path>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape `[` and `]` because they are interpreted as characters classes in regexp and not literal square brackets:

```
$ sed 's/\[$HelloWorld\]/$HelloWorld/g' file
string $HelloWord
```

You can make use of capture groups here:

```
$ sed 's/\[\($HelloWorld\)\]/\1/g' file
string $HelloWord
```

Use `sed 's/[][]//g'` if you want to remove all square brackets from a file:

```
# First check changes are correct
$ sed 's/[][]//g' file
string $HelloWorld

# Store the change back to the file 
$ sed -i 's/[][]//g' file

# Store changes back to the file and create back up of the original 
$ sed -i.bak 's/[][]//g' file
```